# $P(X \ge a) = P(g(X) \ge g(a))$ for some function $g$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Several times in proofs I've come across a 'trick' where authors will say $P(X \ge a) = P(g(X) \ge g(a))$ for some function $g$ and random variable $X$. The function $g(x)$ is usually $e^x$ or $x^2$. I was wondering if this statement was true for any function $g$? (or random variable $X$ for that matter). I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence that the two functions I've seen are both convex?

Comment: I think it has to at least be continuous and monotonically increasing (in a relevant range).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need that $g$ is a strictly increasing function:

$$x<y \implies g(x) < g(y)$$

Then

$$P(X \geq a) = P(g(X) \geq g(a))$$

follows because we have $\{X \geq a \}=\{g(X) \geq g(a)\}$.

Indeed, $$X(\omega) \geq a \iff g(X(\omega)) \geq g(a)$$

Both the functions $e^x, x^2$ satisfy this (for $x^2$ you must be careful with the domain though!).

---

For an arbitrary function this can fail badly. For example, consider the homeomorphism

$$g(x)=-x$$

This will flip the inequality.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense